# Client Button Click event not triggered when clicking on button text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using RadToolBar Button with FontAwesome icon and text. When I click on FontAwesome icon on button, it trigger the OnClientButtonClicked function, but when I click on button text,it wont triggered.

I tried search but I don't find any solution, how to fix this,What I am missing?

```
function OnClientButtonClicked(sender,args)
    {
        var button = args.get_item();

        if (button._properties._data.text == "ADD Step")
        {
            //TODO:
        }            
    }




<telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server" OnClientButtonClicked="OnClientButtonClicked">
<CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="ADD Step">                                            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button class="btn tertiary medium" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Step</button>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton IsSeparator="true"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Import Step">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button class="btn tertiary medium" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>Import Step</button>
                </ItemTemplate>                                             
        </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Comment: did you try console.log(button._properties._data.text). Is it ADD Step?

Comment: @mstfyldzit doesn't matter for my issue.yes I tried and its logs Add Step,My question is "OnClientButtonClicked" is called when I click on button icon,but if I click on button text it wont called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put it into a `<span>` with a minimum size. I think this would make trigger. or into a or some HTML tag.

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <button class="btn tertiary medium" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> <span>Add Step</span></button>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to my question.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I am sorry, I understood other thing :)

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I tried <div> and <p> tag around text,but it wraps the text below the button icon. I put text into <span> and it works as expected.I request you to update the same in answer. Can you let me know,How you got this?

Comment: You are welcome. I had the same problem time ago while trying to create a clickable text. It seems like that was the same issue.